# The use of "though"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I'd like to know why the use of *though* in this sentence is wrong.

> Besides this he just gives money to the man and lets him walk away though of his bad injuries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"although/though" introduces a clause with a verb and is a subordinating conjunction.
Here you have no clause but only a noun group "of his bad injuries". So you need a preposition: in spite of his bad injuries.
There is a variant for in spite of something: despite something (without of).

Comment: It can also introduce a "reduced clause" where the verb disappears leaving a noun or adjective phrase: _Though angry, he managed to speak civilly_; _though an idiot, he was quite likable_. This is a bit literary, and it certainly doesn't apply here.

Comment: But it is a good remark, thanks. This shortening of a clause by dropping the verb is mostly found when the verb is a form of to be.

Answer (score 0):

"...though he had bad injuries" would be more correct. I guess there should be an independent phrase after though. I can't think of any other kind .